# Can someone elaborate on this proposition about creating manifolds with boundary?

Tags: differential-topology

In Guillemin and Pollack they state:

> **Proposition.** The product of a manifold without boundary, $X$ and a manifold with boundary $Y$ is another manifold with boundary.
>   Furthermore:
>
> $$ \partial(X \times Y) = X \times \partial Y$$
>
> and:
>
> $$ \dim ( X \times Y) = \dim(X) + \dim(Y)$$

The proof goes as follows:

> If $U \in R^k$ and $V \in H^l$ are open, then:
>
> $$ U \times V \in R^k \times H^l = H^{k+l} $$
>
> is open. Moreover, if $\phi : U \to X$  and $\psi : V \to Y$ are local
>   parameterizations, so is $\phi \times \psi : U \times V \to X \times Y$.

So, I see that as any local parameterization is in $R^k \times H^l = H^{k+l}$ this implies the $\dim$ is $k + l$, and therefore $\dim(X) + \dim(Y)$, but it is not clear to me why this proof illustrates:

$$\partial (X \times Y) = X \times \partial Y$$

Could someone clarify why $\partial (X \times Y) = X \times \partial Y$? If you need more clarification, please ask.